# Calculate order sequence in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-order-by, sequence

I am new to BigQuery SQL and struggling with calculating an "order sequence" from a table of customer orders.

In my example, I am working with customer purchases, where I have the sales channel, the unique order number, the order date and other purchase as well as customer information. I am also joining two tables in my query to get all the necessary data into one table.

This is how my current query looks like:

```
SELECT
t1.channel as sales_channel,
t1.number as order_number,
t1.date as order_date,
t1.email as customer,
t1.price as gross_price,
t1.sku as SKU,
t1.quantity as sku_quantity,
t1.sku_price as sku_price,
t2.order_status,
t2.weight,
t2.size
FROM order_itemsinfo t1
JOIN order_statusinfo t2
ON t1.number= t2.number
where t1.price > 0 AND 
t1.sku in ("ABC-233-20L","DEF-100-10Y")
```

However, based on this query, I also want to add another column with the "order sequence", which is calculated on a customer level and based on the purchase date.

Hence, the result should look like the following with the calculated order sequence:

```
sales_channel | order_number | order_date | customer              | ...  | order_sequence
US            | US184746     | 2020-01-04 | customer1@sample.com  | ...  | 1
US            | US752646     | 2020-02-14 | customer1@sample.com  | ...  | 2
US            | US975246     | 2020-02-28 | customer1@sample.com  | ...  | 3
US            | US997512     | 2020-05-07 | customer1@sample.com  | ...  | 4
FR            | FR210000     | 2020-03-22 | customer2@sample.com  | ...  | 1
FR            | FR354884     | 2020-04-10 | customer2@sample.com  | ...  | 2
FR            | FR578410     | 2020-04-30 | customer2@sample.com  | ...  | 3
UK            | UK454100     | 2020-04-01 | customer3@sample.com  | ...  | 1
UK            | UK884212     | 2020-08-21 | customer3@sample.com  | ...  | 2
IT            | IT898990     | 2020-08-04 | customer4@sample.com  | ...  | 1
IT            | IT999181     | 2020-10-24 | customer4@sample.com  | ...  | 2
IT            | IT999652     | 2020-11-06 | customer4@sample.com  | ...  | 3
```

How would I best integrate this in my query above without interfering with the JOIN and my filters?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would use window functions:

```
SELECT . . .,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ii.customer ORDER BY ii.date) as seqnum
FROM order_itemsinfo ii JOIN
     order_statusinfo si
     ON ii.number = si.number
WHERE ii.price > 0 AND 
      ii.sku in ('ABC-233-20L', 'DEF-100-10Y');
```

Note that I changed the table aliases.  Instead of using meaningless letters, these are abbreviations for the table names.  That makes the query much simpler to follow.

Comment: Hey Gordon! Thanks a lot for your reply! I am not sure if the code correctly resolves my issue, since it returns very large values. What I want to do is to add the order sequence **per customer**, as in the example above. So for each customer, the count starts at 1 for their oldest purchase and ends with N, depending on the total number of orders N per customer. So if **customer A** purchased for the very first time on 01-01-2020, this would be number "1", the customer's second order on 04-07-2020 should be marked as "2" and so on.

Comment: I saw that you used "sales_channel", which is actually not of any relevance. Maybe my example above was bad, but just imagine that the sales channel is the same for all lines in my example above. Does it mean I just need to replace `ii.channel` by `ii.email` in your code above? Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @emil_rore . . . It looks like the sequence was per channel.  I updated the answer to use `customer` instead.